# Installation doesn't start, kernel thread helper message and blinking keyboard LEDs

Tags: installation, kernel

I finally got my old computer to boot from a cd, then it loads the cd and i can't get to the installation. Instead a load of messages appear, like `28603967] kernel_thread_helper`.

It just stops there... My keyboard then starts blinking as if someone is constantly pressing scroll lock and caps lock. The only thing moving on the screen is a blinking underscore (`_`) at the bottom of it.

Comment: I had that same problem with my old computer too, not from the CD, but from the HD. Unfortunately (for you), in my case the solution was a simple press of the reset button and give another try to the boot. I *suspected* that I needed to give some time to BIOS to recognize my USB external HD case (it was a temporary use until I got my laptop back from repair) whenever I powered the system on. It wouldn't generate these errors every time, but every time the reset button would solve this freeze.

Comment: You'll need to post more specific information to get meaningful help.  If you want you can take a photo of the screen showing the whole error message, or just type them in.

Answer (score 2):

The blinking lights indicate a kernel panic where the kernel has basically been booted from the cpu. It's very, very bad. Normally it's caused by faulty hardware, but sometimes it can be caused by bad acpi support or some very bad bug in Linux.

In order to figure out what the issue is, we'd need to see what kind of message appears on the screen. You might have to type out the entire thing or write it to a notepad so you can type it in here. Failing all else, seek a computer expert to do your install for you.

You may have to settle for an earlier version of Ubuntu for now.